# Something in car is interfering with iPhone GPS

Tags: electrical, gps, interference

This is going to sound ridiculous but there is no other explanation.

I used phone GPS while driving in my car for the past 3 years. 3 different phones, that is, and they all worked fine. I was recently in an accident and the car went away for repairs and they had to take off the front bumper, parking sensors, etc, to do the repairs. When the car came back a month later, I noticed that my phone GPS was going crazy while I was navigating home. It would detect my location, not move at all while I'm driving, and then randomly appear elsewhere with misleading directions. My partners phone also experiences the same thing in my car.

I never thought it could be car, so I reset location settings etc, everything. Still, GPS goes crazy inside car. This is even when the phone has no physical contact with car either through charger or holder. I then went into my partners car for a similar drive and GPS was working fine.

I can only assume now that something happened during the repairs that is causing interference with the GPS as someone suggested [on my question on stack apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420453/ios-14-5-1-iphone-12-pro-gps-loses-current-location-while-driving?noredirect=1#comment590899_420453).

Is this possible and if so what could it be really?

**Update**
The car got [ceramic coating](https://www.pomponazzi.com.au/) more than six months ago. The windshield was also coated. Is it possible this could be causing issues?

Comment: You need to determine if it's your phone or other GPS devices are effected the same way.

Comment: Or aliens have installed their GPS-jammer equipment while the car was in the shop.

Comment: @EᑎOT Yes, that's possible. Improbable, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  If something in the car is generating interference in the 1.5 GHz band then it can easily block the very faint signals from GPS satellites.  What could be doing this is another question.  Conceivably almost any electronic circuit could do this if it’s damaged somehow, but I’d be inclined to think that the ignition would be the most likely thing.

Comment: I recently had new parking sensors installed. Could they be a cause?

Comment: They are typically ultrasonic rather than radio-based, but essentially any electronics that isn’t shielded properly could be the cause.  If you walk round the car you may be able to identify the area where interference is worst.  There are apps for apple and android that give you information on the signal quality (HDOP)

Comment: Heya. Please check my update. Is it possible ceramic coating could be causing the GPS blocking issue? The windshield was also coated.

Comment: Ceramic coating shouldn't interfere as it doesn't contain metallic particles.
Parking sensors are not activated at all times so it couldn't be them. Is there anything else you've done to the car you haven't mentioned yet, such as window tint?

Comment: I wouldn’t be sure that a coating described as ceramic doesn’t contain metallic particles.  Perhaps you know more than I do about when parking sensors are activated- care to share?

Comment: @Frog i have found my OBD2 scanner and I got three codes:
P0736, U0264, and P005902. P0736 is exhaust camshaft issue. Could that possibly be a cause of the interference somehow?

Comment: I don’t know, but if OBD is showing the code then the electronics must be detecting that somehow, so perhaps that is the cause.