# Can issue with P0736 error code produce EM Interference?

Tags: obd-ii, mercedes-benz, camshaft

I have had an issue with a car where [phone GPS doesn't work inside the vehicle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/82906/something-in-car-is-interfering-with-iphone-gps). I have just connected my OBD2 diagnostics tool and ran it. I got back 3 issues:

1. **P0736** ME - Motor electronics: continuous camshaft adjustment(LEFT). Incorrect position of the exhaust camshaft(POO23)
2. **U0264** COMAND APS(A40/3) : C264 communication with backup camera has a malfunction.
3. **P005902** SRS - Supplemental restraint system : Generic communication fault code.

Any one of those three issues could be causing the interference issue, or non of them at all. Would anyone know if any of these 3 issues could cause or produce interference that can interfere with GPS signal.

**GPS issue in summary**: get into car, turn on Google Maps, Apple maps, or Waze, they all cant connect to GPS, they sit in one place confused on direction and movement. Go to another car and they work fine. Issue has been experienced by Mercedes technicians too so its not a phone issue.

Please help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would be more inclined to believe the body structure, body material and\or insulation of this car is obstructing the G.P.S. signal. Many times when you're at a certain location where satellite signal strength is low, walls and other obstacles will obstruct the signals. You might try going to your phone settings and see if your G.P.S. accuracy is set to high, but I don't think these faults are related to your G.P.S. problem. It would be a great idea to repair the car so there are no faults. That way if I'm wrong you have G.P.S. and a properly running vehicle. 2 of these faults are pretty important and should be addressed anyways.

Comment: Cheers. I am getting those codes addressed next week by Merc mechanics. Will let you know if that makes a difference.